# How to read xml node and replace value of node in groovy script?

Tags: xml, groovy

I am looking Groovy code for below required.

I need to read the Xml node and replace the value of node with some value. let say i need to replace number with $.

Input Xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><person>
<dob>19-01-1987</dob>
<nationalidinformation>
    <nationalid>14-9875-6a</nationalid>
</nationalidinformation>
</person>
```

Expected Xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><person>
<dob>$$-$$-$$$$</dob>
<nationalidinformation>
    <nationalid>$$-$$$$-$a</nationalid>
</nationalidinformation>
</person>
```

Please help me with code to get this.Thanks in advance

```
def Message processData(Message message) {
  def body_xml= message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String
  Node root = new XmlParser().parseText(body_xml)
  root.'**'.findAll { it.name.text() == 'dob' }.toString().replaceAll("\\d", "$")
  def xml = XmlUtil.serialize(root)
  message.setBody(xml)
  return message
}
```

Comment: That's not valid XML as it's missing a closing tag. Also, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: there is a typo error end tag are missing </person>

Comment: Cool, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i tried with below code. but values are not changed in dob tagdef Message processData(Message message) {

 def body_xml= message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String;
 Node root = new XmlParser().parseText(body_xml);
 root.'**'.findAll{it.name.text() == 'dob'}.toString().replaceAll("\\d", "$");

 def xml = XmlUtil.serialize(root);
 message.setBody(xml); 

return message;
}

Comment: Updated your question with that code 

Comment: please help me with correct code

Comment: Can you try below?  I have no idea what `Message` is, so this is a guess

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know what `Message` is, but assuming you can call `getBody()` and `setBody(x)` on it, the following should work (I've added comments to explain the changes):

```
import groovy.xml.*

// Don't need a def, as we're specifying a type
Message processData(Message message) {

  // This is shorter than you had it, and should still work  
  String body_xml = message.getBody(String)

  def root = new XmlParser().parseText(body_xml)

  // Find the first <dob> element, and set it's value to $
  root.'**'.find { it.name() == 'dob' }.value = '$'

  // Serialize it back (this will call setBody())
  message.body = XmlUtil.serialize(root)

  // Last line returns the value, no need for `return`
  message
}
```

Comment: output is return with single $ in dob tag but i required numbers should replace with $.    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><person>
<dob>$</dob>
<jobinformation>
<event>H</event>
</jobinformation>
<nationalidinformation>
<nationalid>14-9875-6a</nationalid>
</nationalidinformation>
</person>

Comment: What numbers do you want?

Comment: I am expecting output as <dob>$$-$$-$$$$</dob> in dob tag, for this input tag is <dob>19-01-1987</dob>

Comment: So you want to replace each number with a $?

Comment: Yes. your correct. need to replace each number with $.